# indexed db error when calling .open

Tags: indexeddb

I am learning indexeddb and after 4 hours of reading, i started a small project. after a while, nothing worked ... so i finally found out an example:

http://pastebin.com/nnrNkk8T#

but I get:

```
InvalidStateError


var request = indexedDB.open('todos', 5);
```

at first, i thought it was because I was using the wrong version of FF but I have 28.0 .. which this feature is supported since 27.

what am I doing wrong...

Comment: If you add window. in front of indexedDB - does it help?

Comment: try opening the database without version indexedDB.open('todos');
btw here is a version of html5rock demo which I maintain https://github.com/denimf/IndexedDbToDo

Comment: @DeniMf I tried that one too but it's still not working.

Comment: timmy do you open your page from filesystem or you run it hosted, indexddb cannot run on pages opened from file system in firefox

Comment: @DeniMf Oh let me try that, I am testing locally, file:///home/drake/test.html

Comment: host it in IIS or apache, indexeddb can't run from file:// in firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Timmy tried to open `IndexedDB` from file system and Firefox doesn't support running IDB from local files: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=643318

The solution is hosting the page in some web server and accessing it from there.

Comment: Jeeze - yeah - forgot that. Really surprises me how many web developers try to run web apps from file://!